# T-SQL Join NULL and NOT NULL Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1] ( [ID1] INT NOT NULL, [ID2] INT NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T2] ( [ID1] INT NOT NULL, [ID2] INT NULL, [VAL] INT NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO [dbo].[T1] ( [ID1], [ID2] )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 )
        ,( 1, 2 )
        ,( 1, 3 )
        ,( 1, 4 )
        ,( 1, 5 )
        ,( 2, 1 );

INSERT  INTO [dbo].[T2] ( [ID1], [ID2], [VAL] )
VALUES  ( 1, NULL, 25000 )
        ,( 1, 2, 30000 )
        ,( 2, NULL, 30000 );
```

Goal:

T1 has a full list of ID1 and ID2 mapping.
T2 is a foreign table with some ID1/ID2 mapped to a Val.

The end goal is to "cross join" T1 and T2 (ID1/ID2) when T2.ID2 = NULL but skip the output of that T1.ID2 when T2.ID2 has a NOT NULL value and keep the VAL from T2 for NOT-NULL T2.ID2s. The performance has to be FAST!!!

Desired output:

```
ID1 ID2 VAL
1   1   25000
1   2   30000 -- T1.ID2 = 2 takes the priority 
1   3   25000
1   4   25000
1   5   25000
2   1   30000
```

My Try:

```
SELECT  [T2].[ID1]
      , [T1].[ID2]
      , [T2].[VAL]
FROM    [dbo].[T1] [T1]
JOIN    [dbo].[T2] [T2]
ON      [T1].[ID1] = [T2].[ID1]
WHERE   [T2].[ID2] IS NULL
        OR [T1].[ID2] IN (SELECT    [T3].[ID2]
                          FROM      [dbo].[T2] [T3]
                          WHERE     [T2].[ID1] = [T3].[ID1] 
                                    AND [T2].[ID2] = [T3].[ID2] )
--ORDER BY  [T2].[ID1]
--        , [T1].[ID2]
--        , [T2].[VAL];
```

Current Output:

```
ID1 ID2 VAL
1   1   25000
1   2   25000
1   3   25000
1   4   25000
1   5   25000
1   2   30000
2   1   30000

DROP TABLE [dbo].[T1];
DROP TABLE [dbo].[T2];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a default value in your lookup table.  You can approach this using `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select t1.id1, t1.id2,
       coalesce(t2.val, t2default.val) as val
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id1 = t2.id1 and t1.id2 = t2.id2 left join
     t2 t2default
     on t1.id1 = t2default.id1 and t2default.id2 is null;
```

Assuming that you have the right indexes on the id columns used in the joins, the performance should be very good.

If you care about performance, an alternative method might be worth a try:

```
select t1.id1, t1.id2, t2.val
from t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t2
      where t2.id1 = t1.id and (t2.id2 is null or t2.id2 = t1.id2)
      order by (case when t2.id2 = t1.id2 then 1 else 2 end)
     ) t2;
```

This seems more complicated to me, but sometimes `apply` has surprisingly good performance characteristics.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this works as expected. Just curious, unless it was a minor oversight, why didn't you coalesce ID2 in the first query (i.e. coalesce(t2.id2,t1.id2) as id2)? Btw, surprisingly, the first solution gave a better exec plan than the second for the above data. Will try the logic with the real/bigger tables and compare. Thanks again.

Comment: @007 . . . That was a typo.  It should be `t1.id2`.